# How do I fix my table of contents of LibreOffice/OpenOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-writer, table-of-contents

I've made a document on Google Drive and I want to add a Table of Content from LibreOffice to it, but all headers are seen as Content 10 by the program, so they are all on one line, instead of indented based on level.